# setRowspan en iText 1.3

Tags: java, itext

Estoy realizando un PDF con **iText 1.3** y ocupo combinar 2 renglones, he investigado que versiones superiores se encuentra el metodo `setRowspan`, pero en la versión que estoy ocupando no se encuentra. ¿Como puedo lograr esa función en iText 1.3?

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
cell.setColspan(2);
table.addCell(cell);
//Primera celda a combinar
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("ALGUN TEXTO"));
cell.setBackgroundColor(colorVerdeOscuro);
table.addCell(cell);
table.addCell("112128");
table.addCell("OTRO TEXTO");
//Segunda celda a combinar
table.addCell("");
document.add(pdfTable);
```